# Embedding PowerPoint inside of asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, powerpoint

I like to embed a PowerPoint side of my ASP.NET Page.
I like to have he same effect as what you see here:

http://www.pptsshare.com/2009/09/powerpoint-presentation-on-aspnet.html

I tried the following but did not seem to do the trick:

```
     <iframe id="pp1" runat="server" src="../Training/Content/PPT1.pptx"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those are being served up from someone's Google drive. If you upload this to your drive, click into the document, go to File -> Publish to the web, and it will give you html for an iframe. Copy and paste that into your .NET page and you should be good.

Here's a [link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37579?hl=en) from Google support on it